# Action on Google rejected because of obligation to use Transactions API

Tags: transactions, action, actions-on-google

The Action on Google I try to deploy was rejected by the AoG Review Team because I need to integrate the `Transactions API`.

As a part of the Action – which is on reporting malfunctions in rented houses – the user must make an appointment for a handyman for carrying out a repair. The user is offered a date/time, which he can accept or reject. In the latter case, a new date/time is proposed. This goes on until the user accepts or cancels.

I do not see how (and why) to use the `Transactions API` in this case. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am using the `Actions SDK`, not `DialogFlow`.

John Pool

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the document on creating [reservations](https://developers.google.com/actions/transactions/physical/dev-guide-physical-reservations), transactions that don't have an associated cost.